# how read excel file in c# console?

Tags: c#, excel, console

how i can open a excel file and read cell by cell in C# but just in Console not in windowsForm ?

```
using System;

namespace nms
{
  class read_from_excel_file
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
         //open excel file 
        //print(cell[1,1])
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The type of the project (Console, Windows Forms, library, etc.) is irrelevant to the way you interop with a MS Office application. Read on the [basics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interop/how-to-access-office-onterop-objects), work your way from there and come back here to ask more focused questions when you get stuck.

Comment: My suggestion is not to use Interop at all. You could use OpenSource libraries as [EPPlus](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus) (the OpenSource version), [SpreadsheetLight](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SpreadsheetLight/), [ExcelDataReader](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ExcelDataReader/) or use the OleDb provider to query an Excel Worksheet as a DataTable. Office Interop requires an Office installation, the others *options* don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add Nuget package "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel" to achieve it.

[image]

Here is a demo.

```
string strFileName = @"D:\test.xls";
object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
Excel.Application excel = new Excel.Application();
Excel.Workbook workBook = excel.Application.Workbooks.Open(strFileName, missing, true, missing, missing, missing,
missing, missing, missing, true, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing);
Excel.Worksheet worksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)workBook.Sheets[1];

// print cell[1,1]
Console.WriteLine(worksheet.Cells[1, 1].Value);
```